# Same script different result

Tags: python, tensorflow, metrics, semantic-segmentation

I wrote a code for calculating the Matthews Correlation Coefficient (MCC) using the [tensorflow-addons library](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/MatthewsCorrelationCoefficient) for a semantic segmentation problem in the multi-class case (3 classes).
I run the script in my personal laptop and got an array with three values (one per each) as I expected.
Then I run the exact same script with the same data and same tensorflow version (TF 2.4.1) in my university computer and the result is just a single value for all the three clasess (no idea how it is calculated though).
How is this possible? How can I obtain always the array with three values no matter which machine the script is running on?

These are the lines of code calling the mcc:

```
mcc_tf = tfa.metrics.MatthewsCorrelationCoefficient(num_classes=3)
mcc_tf.update_state(gt_array_2, pred_array_2)
mcc =  mcc_tf.result().numpy()
```

where `gt_array_2` and `pred_array_2` are the grounf truth and predictions arrays.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different options and just in case someone faces the same problem in the future, you just need to downgrade tensorflow-addons to the version 0.12.1 to generate each class' MCC.